# Bulk emails failing - showing as 'Running'. How to debug?

Tags: civimail, drupal, 4.6.10

Bulk scheduled emails are failing - they are shown as 'Running' but never finish - one mailing has taken a day and a half to send 30 out of 47 emails, and subsequent mailings are doing nothing.  The hosting company can't see a problem, so my guess now is that Civi is choking on a database problem.  I can start a mailing job manually in the UI and it starts but never finishes.  There is a plethora of civicrm_mailing_* tables to look at.  The civicrm_mailing_spool table is empty, and civicrm_mailing_queue has over 41k rows.  Mailer batch limit is set to 120, everything else defaults, we're using the same server to send the emails (no Mailjet or similar). Civi level is 4.6.10 with Drupal. Can someone give me a guide or hint where to look? Which tables..?

Comment: Some progress on this.  2 bulk emails that were 'Running' and doing nothing I have deleted.  I submitted another 'test' and it doesn't run - just sits in 'Scheduled' status.  However I can trigger the job from the 'Scheduled Jobs' UI and it runs OK.  The CiviCRM cron is running OK as far as I can see (at least I can run the Drupal cron) but is doing nothing, it seems.  I get no error messages..

Comment: The problem was fixed by adding the string --no-check-certificate to the wget in the cron statement  We moved servers a few weeks ago & there seems to be a problem with the SSL certificate not being recognised by the wget.  This workaround is mentioned in Civi's Wiki at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-RunALLScheduledJobsviaURL%29